# Android.Check if user is logged and open Menu activity

Tags: java, android

How can i check if user is logged in?If is logged every time when i open the app while user is logged open the menu activity!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to use your own solution, or a standard one from Google. If you ONLY care about google signin, you could try this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

There is also the firebase approach (they acquired by google and integrated into their ecosystem): https://firebase.google.com/docs/ and **specifically** look at the section on authentication here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
It allows you to sign in with google, facebook, twitter, github, anonymous, as well as your custom auth backend.

Finally, you can store an indicator of the currently logged in user (just say the firebase id user id) in local private shared prefs so your app can consutl the recorded signed-in id and if it's null, you can initiate a formal sign-in UI flow, otherwise attempt to log in 'quietly'.

Comment: Thank you!My user is connected with email&password, can i check with googleApi if is logged?

Comment: then i'd actually recommend the firebase cross-platform sign in. i'll update the answer.  firebase got acquired by google and they recently completed a massive integration so they play very well with the google ecosystem

Comment: My app is connected to firebase database, log in, create account , everything works fine but every time when i run my app starts with log in activity and i want to check, if was logated to open menu activity.Thanks!

Comment: Oh so it is just for you to drive your own UIs? Store an indicator in shared prefs. Perhaps the firebase user id of the currently recorded signed-in user. Then you can consult that id and if it's non-null, you don't display your special log in activity.